# Error al iniciar SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

Tengo un problema con SQL SERVER 2012, el inconveniente es que al momento de abrirlo me envía un error que me indica que dejo de funcionar como si se trabara algún proceso, lo raro es que estuvo funcionando y de la nada comenzó a dar el error, ya no puedo abrir SQL porque no me lo permite, instale nuevamente SQL SERVER y me sigue dando el mismo inconveniente, reinicie servicios, repare el producto, reinicie mil veces la maquina y persiste, alguien podría ayudarme!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el mensaje del LOG

> 2017-07-17 15:04:18.65 Servidor    SQL Server is terminating because of a system shutdown. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>
> 2017-07-17 15:04:38.92 spid20s     Service Broker manager has shut down.
>
> 2017-07-17 15:04:38.92 spid20s     Error: 17054, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>
> 2017-07-17 15:04:38.92 spid20s     The current event was not reported to the Windows Events log. Operating system error = (null). You may need to clear the Windows Events log if it is full.
>
> 2017-07-17 15:04:52.21 spid4s      .NET Framework runtime has been stopped.
>
> 2017-07-17 15:04:59.54 spid4s      SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Podrías editar la pregunta y escribir todo el log de error que se te da por favor, y una pregunta, cuando "instalaste nuevamente" SQL Server, eliminaste la instancia que tenias generada?. Saludos

Comment: Ya coloque el mensaje del LOG, si elimine la instancia que estaba generada anteriormente.

Comment: una busqueda en google del error dice que para saber que error tenes, limpies el log de errores de windows ya que esta completo. busque este error primero: 17054.. proba eso y fijate que pasa

Answer (score 1):

Revisando búsquedas con el error 17054, encontré algunas posibles soluciones:

1. Limpia tu Log, al parecer se encuentra lleno.
2. Verifica si la cuenta de servicio del SQL Server tiene permisos de escritura sobre la carpeta del log.
3. En el Administrador de configuración del SQL Server, verifica que el SQL Browser service está ejecutándose, también revisa si esta en automático, y no en manual, de lo contrario no arrancaría sino hasta que lo hagas.

Realiza todas esas verificaciones y prueba. Saludos.